# Last 4 bytes of a value in solidity

Tags: solidity

`bytes4(*)` gives first 4 bytes of `*` in Solidity. Is it possible to get last 4 bytes of `*` easily in Solidity? Or does a custom function have to be written?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on *. If you have a `calldata bytes` this can be easily done with slices: see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#array-slices